# SVN externals and TortoiseSVN - why did the order of local path and URL switch places?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I have a code which helps me updating svn:externals property when creating a new branch of a project.

Previously I had an older Tortoise SVN version. My code for svn:externals of my lib folder looked like this:

```
php/somelib  svn://myotherrepo/lib/php/somelib
```

Some time ago I upgraded to TortoiseSVN 1.7. Now when I click Edit button, everything seems fine, the path goes first and then goes the URL. But the default edit mode is not convenient if I want to add a bunch of externals. So I click Edit->Advanced to get to the raw text of the svn:externals property ... what? Now all the externals are reversed:

```
svn://myotherrepo/lib/php/somelib  php/somelib
```

and my old svn:externals prepared code does not work, I have to reorganize it.

**Why did URL and path change places? Did it happen in some newer version of SVN or is it just a feature of the new TortoiseSVN?**

I guess, this issue makes many tutorials on the web wrong because now the paths are reversed...

Answer (score 3):

> Why did URL and path change places?

Because authors made this change *long time ago* (and documented it, BTW)

> this issue makes many tutorials on the web wrong because now the paths are reversed

No.

From `svn help ps`

> Use of the following format is discouraged but is supported for interoperability with Subversion 1.4 and earlier clients:
>
> LOCALPATH [-r PEG] URL